# uninitialized constant Bundler with pod init

Tags: cocoapods, bundler

I'm trying to run `pod init` in a new xcode project. But I'm getting the error:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:45:in `full_gem_path': uninitialized constant Bundler::Plugin::API::Source (NameError)
    from /Users/nicholasstephan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:144:in `block in full_require_paths'
    from /Users/nicholasstephan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:143:in `map'
    from /Users/nicholasstephan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:143:in `full_require_paths'
    from /Users/nicholasstephan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:76:in `contains_r
```

I've re-installed bundler with `sudo gem install bundler` a couple of times.

Is this an `rvm` issue? What's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

try running `gem update` and `gem cleanup`. I think this issue comes up with bundler 1.13.0.

Comment: Thanks. But still the same problem. `gem update` runs through fine, then `gem cleanup` gives me this: `Attempting to uninstall bundler-1.13.1
Unable to uninstall bundler-1.13.1:
 Gem::InstallError: bundler is not installed in GEM_HOME, try:
 gem uninstall -i /Users/nicholasstephan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global bundler` for each install gem. And `pod init` still gives me the same `NameError`.

Comment: try `gem uninstall bundler` (say yes to everything)
`gem install bundler --version '1.12'`

Comment: Strangely, I'm still get the same error. In the end, swithing rvm to ruby 2.3.0 seemed to fix it. But I still don't understand what was going on.